# How to merge two files based on data in multiple columns?

Tags: if-statement, awk, multiple-columns

I have two separate files, each containing a different number of columns which I want to merge based on data in multiple columns.

file1

```
VMNF01000015.1  1769465 1769675 .   .   -   Focub_II5_mimp_1
VMNF01000014.1  3225875 3226081 .   .   +   Focub_II5_mimp_1
VMNF01000014.1  3226046 3226081 .   .   -   Focub_II5_mimp_1
VMNF01000014.1  3585246 3585281 .   .   -   Focub_II5_mimp_1
VMNF01000014.1  3692468 3692503 .   .   -   Focub_II5_mimp_1
VMNF01000014.1  3715380 3715415 .   .   +   Focub_II5_mimp_1
VMNF01000014.1  2872478 2872511 .   .   -   Focub_II5_mimp_1
```

file2

```
VMNF01000014.1  3225875-3226081(+)  gtacttcagcctggattcaaacttattgcatcccactgta
VMNF01000014.1  3226046-3226081(-)  tacacacctgcgaatactttttgcatcccactgta
VMNF01000015.1  1769465-1769675(-)  gtacttcagcctggattcaaacttattgcatcccactgta
VMNF01000014.1  3692468-3692503(-)  tacagtgggatgcaaaaagtattcgcaggtgt
VMNF01000014.1  3715380-3715415(+)  gtacttcagcctggattcaaacttattgcatcccactgta
VMNF01000014.1  3585246-3585281(-)  tacagtgggatgcaaaaagtattcgcaggtgt
VMNF01000014.1  2872478-2872511(-)  gtacttcagcctggattcaaacttattgcatcccactgta
```

First, I think I need to create another 2 columns in file2, separating numbers by "-" and creating a new column for "(*)", but I cannot work out how to separate the numbers without replacing "(-)" too. So far I have been using this command:

```
awk '{gsub("-","\t",$2);print;}'
```

Once this has been done, I would like to add the last column in file2 to file1. I have been able to do this using the following command:

```
awk 'NR==FNR {a[$1]=$3; next} {print $1,$2,$3,$4,$5,$6,$7,a[$1];}' file2 file1 > file3.
```

However, the data does not match. It is matched based on the entry in column 1. The data in column 1 is the same in many instances, so the data in column 8 of file3 only matches one of the entries, and doesn't match the data in column 2 or 3 in file1 e.g.

file3:

```
VMNF01000015.1  1769465 1769675 .   .   -   Focub_II5_mimp_1    gtacttcagcctggattcaaacttattgcatcccactgta
VMNF01000014.1  3225875 3226081 .   .   +   Focub_II5_mimp_1    gtacttcagcctggattcaaacttattgcatcccactgta
VMNF01000014.1  3226046 3226081 .   .   -   Focub_II5_mimp_1    gtacttcagcctggattcaaacttattgcatcccactgta
VMNF01000014.1  3585246 3585281 .   .   -   Focub_II5_mimp_1    gtacttcagcctggattcaaacttattgcatcccactgta
VMNF01000014.1  3692468 3692503 .   .   -   Focub_II5_mimp_1    gtacttcagcctggattcaaacttattgcatcccactgta
VMNF01000014.1  3715380 3715415 .   .   +   Focub_II5_mimp_1    gtacttcagcctggattcaaacttattgcatcccactgta
VMNF01000014.1  2872478 2872511 .   .   -   Focub_II5_mimp_1    gtacttcagcctggattcaaacttattgcatcccactgta
```

Even if I was able to separate the data in column 2 of file2, I would still have the same problem as the data in column 2 is the same in some instances. What I need is code that says something along the lines of: sperate the data in column 2 (see below);

```
VMNF01000014.1  3225875    3226081    (+)   gtacttcagcctggattcaaacttattgcatcccactgta
```

then:

if $1,$2,$3 in file1 match $1,$2,$3 in file2, print $1,$2,$3,$4,$5,$6,$7 from file1 and add $5 from file2.

How can I do this? I know that awk can use if statements, but I don't know how to use them in awk.

Any advice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you please try following.

```
awk '
FNR==NR{
  split($2,array,"[-(]")
  mainarray[$1,array[1],array[2]]=$NF
  next
}
(($1,$2,$3) in mainarray){
  print $0,mainarray[$1,$2,$3]
}
'  Input_file2  Input_file1
```

***2nd solution:*** Since OP is getting an error in above code so made a little change in above.

```
awk '
FNR==NR{
  split($2,array,"[-(]")
  key=$1 OFS array[1] OFS array[2]
  mainarray[key]=$NF
  next
}
{ key = $1 OFS $2 OFS $3 }
(key in mainarray){
  print $0,mainarray[key]
}
'  Input_file2  Input_file1
```

***Explanation:*** Adding detailed explanation for above code.

```
awk '                                       ##Starting awk program from here.
FNR==NR{                                    ##Checking condition FNR==NR when  Input_file2 is being read.
  split($2,array,"[-(]")                    ##Splitting 2nd field into an array named array where delimiter is - OR (
  mainarray[$1,array[1],array[2]]=$NF       ##Creating mainarray index of $1,array[1],array[2] and value is current line is last field.
  next                                      ##next will skip all further statements from here.
}
(($1,$2,$3) in mainarray){                  ##Checking condition if $1,$2,$3 of current line is present in mainaarray.
  print $0,mainarray[$1,$2,$3]              ##Printing current line with value of mainarray with index of $1,$2,$3
}
'  Input_file2  Input_file1                 ##Mentioning Input_file names here.
```

Comment: I have noticed that in some instances the (-) or (+) are also required for ensuring the correct sequence in column 8, is there a way to include this too? Can it be done by adding another array to key?

Answer (score 2):

```
$ awk '
    { key=$1 OFS $2 OFS $3 }
    NR==FNR { map[key]=$NF; next }
    { print $0, map[key] }
' FS='[[:space:](-]+' file2 FS=' ' file1
VMNF01000015.1  1769465 1769675 .   .   -   Focub_II5_mimp_1 gtacttcagcctggattcaaacttattgcatcccactgta
VMNF01000014.1  3225875 3226081 .   .   +   Focub_II5_mimp_1 gtacttcagcctggattcaaacttattgcatcccactgta
VMNF01000014.1  3226046 3226081 .   .   -   Focub_II5_mimp_1 tacacacctgcgaatactttttgcatcccactgta
VMNF01000014.1  3585246 3585281 .   .   -   Focub_II5_mimp_1 tacagtgggatgcaaaaagtattcgcaggtgt
VMNF01000014.1  3692468 3692503 .   .   -   Focub_II5_mimp_1 tacagtgggatgcaaaaagtattcgcaggtgt
VMNF01000014.1  3715380 3715415 .   .   +   Focub_II5_mimp_1 gtacttcagcctggattcaaacttattgcatcccactgta
VMNF01000014.1  2872478 2872511 .   .   -   Focub_II5_mimp_1 gtacttcagcctggattcaaacttattgcatcccactgta
```