# Using symbols to correctly match columns in Awk?

Tags: awk, multiple-columns

I have two separate files, Input_File1 and Input_File2, each containing a different number of columns which I have merged ([with some help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61143976/how-to-merge-two-files-based-on-data-in-multiple-columns/61144202?noredirect=1#comment108248292_61144202)) based on data in multiple columns.

So far a column is added to Input_File1 to create a new file (file3) based on data matching in column 1, 2, and 3 of Input_File1, and columns 1, 2, and 3 in Input_File2. On the whole, this works well. However, there a few circumstances where the data in column 1, 2, and 3 in Input_File1 and Input_File2 are the same, but the output in file3 should be different. This is based on another feature in Input_File1 and Input_File2, the presence of a "-" or "+".

Input_File1

```
VMNF01000007.1  6294425 6294650 .   .   +   Focub_B2_mimp_2
VMNF01000008.1  1441418 1441616 .   .   -   Focub_II5_mimp_3
VMNF01000008.1  1441418 1441616 .   .   -   Focub_B2_mimp_1
VMNF01000008.1  1441418 1441616 .   .   +   Focub_B2_mimp_2
```

Input_File2

```
VMNF01000007.1  6294425-6294650(+)  tacagtggggggcaataagtatgaataccctttggtgtactgacacacacctctt
VMNF01000008.1  1441418-1441616(-)  gggagtgtattgttttttctgccgctagcccattttaacatttagagtgtgcata
VMNF01000008.1  1441418-1441616(-)  gggagtgtattgttttttctgccgctagcccattttaacatttagagtgtgcata
VMNF01000008.1  1441418-1441616(+)  tacagtggggggcaataagtatgaataccctttgatgtactgacacacacctctt
```

As you can see, the data in the last two rows of Input_File2 is the same apart from the (-) and (+), as a result, the sequence following is different.

When file3 is produced, the sequences in column 8 do not differ as they do in Input_File2. This is because only the data `VMNF01000008.1    1441418 1441616` is considered when matching columns.

current file3 (note the sequences and + or - last two rows):

```
VMNF01000007.1  6294425 6294650 .   .   -   Focub_B2_mimp_1 tacagtggggggcaataagtatgaataccctttggtgtactgacacacacctctt
VMNF01000008.1  1441418 1441616 .   .   -   Focub_II5_mimp_3 tacagtggggggcaataagtatgaataccctttgatgtactgacacacacctctt
VMNF01000008.1  1441418 1441616 .   .   -   Focub_B2_mimp_1 tacagtggggggcaataagtatgaataccctttgatgtactgacacacacctctt
VMNF01000008.1  1441418 1441616 .   .   +   Focub_B2_mimp_2 tacagtggggggcaataagtatgaataccctttgatgtactgacacacacctctt
```

file3 should in fact look like (note the sequences and + or - last two rows):

```
VMNF01000007.1  6294425 6294650 .   .   -   Focub_B2_mimp_1 tacagtggggggcaataagtatgaataccctttggtgtactgacacacacctctt
VMNF01000008.1  1441418 1441616 .   .   -   Focub_II5_mimp_3 gggagtgtattgttttttctgccgctagcccattttaacatttagagtgtgcata
VMNF01000008.1  1441418 1441616 .   .   -   Focub_B2_mimp_1 gggagtgtattgttttttctgccgctagcccattttaacatttagagtgtgcata
VMNF01000008.1  1441418 1441616 .   .   +   Focub_B2_mimp_2 tacagtggggggcaataagtatgaataccctttgatgtactgacacacacctctt
```

Where, as in Input_File2, the sequences differ when there is a "-" or "+".

So it operates in much the same way as the previous code, just with the addition of matching the "-" or "+" in Input_File1 and Input_File2 to ensure that the sequence that follows is correct. How can I add using "-" or "+" to determine the sequence that should be added in column 8 to the previous code?

This is the code I am using ([from here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61143976/how-to-merge-two-files-based-on-data-in-multiple-columns/61144202?noredirect=1#comment108248292_61144202)):

```
awk '
FNR==NR{
  split($2,array,"[-(]")
  key=$1 OFS array[1] OFS array[2]
  mainarray[key]=$NF
  next
}
{ key = $1 OFS $2 OFS $3 }
(key in mainarray){
  print $0,mainarray[key]
}
'  Input_file2  Input_file1
```

Any advice? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you please try following.

```
awk '
FNR==NR{
  split($2,array,"[-(]")
  key=$1 OFS array[1] OFS array[2]
  ++count1[key]
  mainarray[key OFS count1[key]]=$NF
  next
}
{
  key=$1 OFS $2 OFS $3
  ++count2[key]
}
((key OFS count2[key]) in mainarray){
  print $0,mainarray[key OFS count2[key]]
}
'  Input_file2  Input_file1
```

Output will be as follows.

```
VMNF01000007.1  6294425 6294650 .   .   +   Focub_B2_mimp_2 tacagtggggggcaataagtatgaataccctttggtgtactgacacacacctctt
VMNF01000008.1  1441418 1441616 .   .   -   Focub_II5_mimp_3 gggagtgtattgttttttctgccgctagcccattttaacatttagagtgtgcata
VMNF01000008.1  1441418 1441616 .   .   -   Focub_B2_mimp_1 gggagtgtattgttttttctgccgctagcccattttaacatttagagtgtgcata
VMNF01000008.1  1441418 1441616 .   .   +   Focub_B2_mimp_2 tacagtggggggcaataagtatgaataccctttgatgtactgacacacacctctt
```

***Explanation:*** Adding detailed explanation for above.

```
awk '                                          ##Starting awk program from here.
FNR==NR{                                       ##Checking condition FNR==NR which will be TRUE when file2 is being read.
  split($2,array,"[-(]")                       ##Splitting 2nd field into array named array with separator -( in it.
  key=$1 OFS array[1] OFS array[2]             ##Creating variable key whose value is $1 array 1st element and array 2nd element.
  ++count1[key]                                ##Creating array count1 with index key and keep increasing its value with 1 here.
  mainarray[key OFS count1[key]]=$NF           ##Creating array mainarray with index key OFS count1[key] value and its value is last column value.
  next                                         ##next will skip all further statements from here.
}
{
  key=$1 OFS $2 OFS $3                         ##Creating variable key with value of first, second and third field values.
  ++count2[key]                                ##Creating array count2 with index key and keepincreasing value with 1 here.
}
((key OFS count2[key]) in mainarray){          ##Checking condition if key OFS count2[key] is present in mainarray
  print $0,mainarray[key OFS count2[key]]      ##Printing current line and value of mainarray whose index is key OFS and value of count2  whose index is key.
}
'  Input_file2  Input_file1                    ##Mentioning Input_file names here.
```